# PDF Print view not the same between development and production environments using wkhtmltopdf/wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf/wicked_pdf to generate a PDF view in Rails on Heroku. I am running Mac OS X locally. 
Here are my versions:
 - Ruby 2.1.3 (Both)
 - Rails 4.0.3 (Both)
 - wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge, 0.12.2.1 (Local)
 - wkhtmltopdf-amd64, 0.12.2.1 (Production)
 - wicked_pdf, 0.11.0 (Both)

The issue I am having is that **some** of the CSS code is rendering correctly on both my local environment and production while **other** css code appears to be ignored. Specifically the code used to repeat table headers and prevent rows from being split over two pages. See below:

```
.table-break { page-break-inside:auto !important; }
.row-break { page-break-inside:avoid !important; page-break-after:auto !important; }
.head-break { display:table-header-group !important; }
```

Here are two images depicting this discrepancy:

**Local:**
https://docs.google.com/a/digiquatics.com/file/d/0B321e2H8Q00CZWlmcFRyaXRRSEk/edit

**Production:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B321e2H8Q00CNDI1VFl3NTdzZlU/view

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you solved this problem? I am having the same issue

Comment: +1 having the same issue, pdf even generate differently from 2 different heroku apps ... i was thinking it was due to 
having different wkhtmltopdf binary versions so downgraded wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf-heroku to .12.3.0 then that it
 was due to different dyno type (standard vs proffessional) being mounted on different infrastructure and wanted to play
 with :disable_smart_shrinking  settings (wkhtmltopdf seems to use a graphical interface or at least graphical server settings) but i couldn't reproduce the case so far ...